# How to directly access Resident Set Size (RSS) of a process from within kernel module?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-module

I want to directly access the Resident Set Size (RSS) of a process from inside a kernel module (I want to take a real time decision based on RSS, so calculating it every time is a bad option for me).

`/proc/$PID/status` has a VmRSS field which I can use, but I do not know how to obtain that information from inside a kernel module.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Include `linux/mm.h`, and call `get_mm_rss(current->mm)` where current is `task_struct*` for a needed task.

---

Use LXR to find what is actually used to get VmRSS:

From [fs/proc/task_mmu.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/fs/proc/task_mmu.c):

```
hiwater_rss = total_rss = get_mm_rss(mm);
[...]
seq_printf(m,
           [...]
           "VmRSS:\t%8lu kB\n"
           [...]
           total_vm << (PAGE_SHIFT-10)
```

Where `get_mm_rss()` is defined in [include/linux/mm.h](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/include/linux/mm.h#L1382):

```
static inline unsigned long get_mm_rss(struct mm_struct *mm)
{
    return get_mm_counter(mm, MM_FILEPAGES) +
        get_mm_counter(mm, MM_ANONPAGES);
}
```

Comment: Alternatively,   `file_pages = task_struct -> mm -> rss_stat.count[MM_FILEPAGES].counter;  
anon_pages = task_struct -> mm -> rss_stat.count[MM_ANONPAGES].counter;  
rss = file_pages + anon_pages;`

Comment: Regarding `total_vm << (PAGE_SHIFT-10)`:  I guess `total_rss` is in pages, so `<< (PAGE_SHIFT-10)` would convert from pages to kilobytes?  For more info, see https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128218 .